# Enter variable into sql table Problems

Tags: php, sql

Ok I am having problems insert a variable into a sql table. Heres my code

```
if (isset ($_GET['comment']))
    $commentEntered = $_GET['comment'];
else
    $commentEntered = "refuse";
```

Above I get the variable
Then I try to pass it to the database with the code below

```
$sql = "insert into $DB_Table (comment) values('$commentEntered');";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($con);
if ($res) {
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "faild";
}// end else
```

My problem is, When I pass a single word it works, But when the text box where comment is received has any spaces in it, It will not insert?

i.e - The user enters Hello - This works

The user enters Hello World - This doesn't work

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: sql injection attack warning, and what's the field type for comment?

Comment: Say hello to [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) for me when you see him...

Comment: Im not too worried as it is only accessed from a personal iPhone app, The field type its passed from is just a normal text field

Comment: the mysql db field type.

Comment: oh just a varchar field to hold 100 characters

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (comment) " . 
       "VALUES ('" . mysql_real_espace_string($commentEntered) . "')";
```

Also, dump the var $commentEntered before the "$sql = ..." line just to see what it outputs to the screen.

```
var_dump($commentEntered);
```

And another thing, try switching from GET request method to POST and grab the data from $_POST.

Comment: `mysql_real_espace_string()`? Is that when you get [Renault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renault_Espace) to do your DB sanitising?

Comment: @DaveRandom What do you mean?

Comment: Well, last time I looked, the function was called `mysql_real_escape_string()`...

Comment: dump the $sql variable, what you see?

Comment: If I echo out $commentEntered to the iPhone app it only return the variable when it contains 1 word. Why won't it read in the entire sentence?

Comment: please, edit your question and add the HTML code of the form.

Answer (score 0):

try to call:

```
 mysql_query("COMMIT");
```

before closing the connection.